# Create multiple random points based on attributes from a different shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, point-in-polygon, random

I have two shapefiles, one (Polygon A) is a fishnet of 1 square kilometer polygons, and the second (polygon B) is a multiple polygon with specific attributes. One of the attribute is the total number of objects.

I came up with a scoring system for the fishnet and only a subset of the fishnet-polygons remains. What I would like to do is to generate X number of random points to the polygon A that fall within a section of polygon B. The # X is the attribute of the section of polygon B. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem people want to solve and have developed tools in the past. Anything like this your first port of call should be the [ArcGIS code sharing](http://codesharing.arcgis.com/?dbid=15267) (previously ArcScripts). Just search for "random points"...

Answer (score 2):

"Create Random Points" has a Constrained Feature Class option. However, you want the points constrained to a specific Polygon. I would Union the two layers, and then experiment with Create Random Points.